# Adding array to multidimensional instead of merging

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array with products and I want to update existing one when user changes quantity instead of adding new. I'm trying to merge but for some reason names in multidimensional array are changed and I don't see why.

It looks like that:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiYxq.png

```
if(!empty($_POST["addquantity"])) {
            $add_id = $_GET['add'];
            $add_quantity = $_POST['addquantity'];
            $sqlOrd = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_product = '$add_id'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlOrd);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $productByCode[] = $row;
            }

            $itemArray = array(
                        $productByCode[0]["id_product"] => array(
                            'name' => $productByCode[0]["name"],
                            'id_product' => $productByCode[0]["id_product"],
                            'quantity' => $_POST["addquantity"],
                            'price' => $productByCode[0]["price"]
                        )
                    );

            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                if(in_array($productByCode[0]["id_product"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode[0]["id_product"] == $k)
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["addquantity"];
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer there is no image of the code - there is an image of an vars content, containing some explanations.. the only thing you could complain is, that it isn't inline..

Comment: You need to break up your code, you are doing way too much in one place. You also are _highly_ vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Philipp maybe http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ is more appropriate? A number of problems here, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the whole code a lot. There is no need for a loop and as you know the keys/id's of the carts items, you could access them directly. In addition to that, you should take care of sql injections and use prepared statements.

```
if (!empty($_POST["addquantity"])) {
    // cast some vars around to prevent sql injection - better use prepared statements
    $add_id = (int)$_GET['add'];
    $add_quantity = (float)$_POST['addquantity'];
    $sqlOrd = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_product = '$add_id' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlOrd);
    $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if (!$product) {
        // some error handling..
    }

    $item = [
        'name' => $product["name"],
        'id_product' => $add_id,
        'quantity' => $add_quantity,
        'price' => $product["price"]
    ];

    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = [];
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$add_id])) {
        $_SESSION["cart_item"][$add_id]["quantity"] += $add_quantity;
    } else {
        $_SESSION["cart_item"][$add_id] = $item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is in `in_array` but you want to use `array_key_exists`.

This IF statements goes directly to ELSE `if(in_array($productByCode[0]["id_product"],$_SESSION["cart_item"]))` because there is no such value in `$_SESSION["cart_item"]`, then `array_merge` resets the keys in this code `$_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);` because there are two items with same integer keys.

So, my quick fix suggestion:

```
if(array_key_exists($productByCode[0]["id_product"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) { 
... rest of the code ...
```

Comment: It's working now. Thank you. Looks like I misread in_array definition